# Android Lollipop 5.0.1 Call Duration bug

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, phone-call

If you look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79592) , there is a bug in **Lollipop 5.0.1** which incorrectly calculates the duration of call from the time of **Call Arrival or Call Start**, **not when you actually start talking**.

The version 5.1 came in, has anyone who has it installed can verify the bug has been corrected or not?

Comment: Even if you dont talk at all the call has a duration.

Comment: Yeah, greenapps thats the case but did u get a chance to see it on 5.1 ?

Comment: Sorry but i still see no bug. You do not talk but can talk. What is wrong with it?

Comment: First, such was not the case with all the versions of Android before since the beginning and secondly as the link mentions, it broke a lot of apps including mine.

Comment: I wonder why you are not able to explain me that talking would trigger a start and silence not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been corrected, just had my 5.1 update and our apps work properly again.

Answer (score 0):

LOL. the issue was that android starts counting call From the moment device start dialing(outgoing call) or the moment device starts ringing(Incoming calls) insted of counting from when the call is picked. Even the missed calls and dialed call which were not picked up were showing call duration>0.

Yes the issue has been fixed in lollipop 5.1.

ref - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79592